# Angular An unhandled exception occurred: EILSEQ: illegal byte sequence, read. When I run 'ng' command

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

When I open the terminal in an Angular project and run `ng` or `ng serve`. I get..

```
An unhandled exception occurred: EILSEQ: illegal byte sequence, read
See "/private/var/folders/f3/jkt2fc9j64xdpvt60mg6s4c40000gn/T/ng-BZg83I/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

When I open the log file it reads...

```
[error] Error: EILSEQ: illegal byte sequence, read
at Object.readSync (fs.js:506:3)
at tryReadSync (fs.js:331:20)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:360:19)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:990:22)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object.<anonymous(/Users/AppProjects/Commercial/ArtifactPro/artifactpro/node_modules/pacote/extract.js:3:12)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
```

In line 3. As indicated by `extract.js`, a module is loaded from `bluebird.js`.

I've no clue what's causing this error. The angular CLI works outside of that project meaning it runs from any directory and also works in any other angular project. Could anyone help with resolving this issue?